# NullPointerException while setActivity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

My app crashes in some devices when try to open an Activity. The problem does not always occur, only on some devices.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.pickerManager = GlobalHolder.getInstance().getPickerManager();
    this.pickerManager.setActivity(TempActivity.this); // <== line with error
    this.pickerManager.pickPhotoWithPermission();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chillihaze.deskeep/com.libraries.imagepicker.TempActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.libraries.imagepicker.e.a(android.app.Activity)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.libraries.imagepicker.e.a(android.app.Activity)' on a null object reference
at com.libraries.imagepicker.TempActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:3)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7148)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7139)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
```

I can't reproduce the error on my devices, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't reproduce the error on my devices, so I can't test it.

Ah, you ***can*** reproduce the error on ***all*** Android devices, you just need to know how ;)

After low memory condition happens, only the *current* Activity gets recreated at first, previous Activity is recreated on back navigation, and all static variables are nulled out (because the process is technically restarted).

Way to reproduce:

- Go to `TempActivity` in your app
- **put your application in background with HOME button**
- **click the TERMINATE button in Android Studio**

[image: terminate button]

- **re-launch the app from the launcher**

You'll experience this phenomenon.

(In AS 4.0 Canary, this won't work, and instead of using the `terminate` button, you'd need to use terminal command `adb shell am kill your.package.name`)

---

The solution is to use `static`s ***with the knowledge and caution*** that the MAIN activity (the one you defined with `<intent-filter>`'s `MAIN` action) is NOT guaranteed to run AT ALL during an Android app's execution, so you should be initializing stuff accordingly.

You can easily return to a DETAIL screen as your First Starting Activity in your app, and the LIST screen would be created only on back navigation.

Also you can check out `intent.putExtra(` and `getIntent()` methods which are kept across process death / low memory condition by Android System.

Comment: +1 for the tip to reproduce the error. With static I get "Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to PickerManager which has field activity pointing to Activity); this is a memory leak" message alert on AS.

Comment: Well yes, that lint warning is correct, as that's what you are doing / have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `this.pickerManager` is not null, on the following line

```
this.pickerManager.setActivity(TempActivity.this)
```